# Keep snackbar over the keyboard with android:fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, snackbar

What happens is: when the snackbar appears on the screen, its shows itself but hidden behind the keyboard and the navigation bar, to fix that I can set `false` on the style's property `"android:fitsSystemWindows"`. But that way the snackbar appears over the keyboard and the navigation bar correctly as expected BUT my layout height doesn't adjust to fit the remaining space let by the keyboard, also hiding the main login button and half of the layout to the user, so he has to dismiss the keyboard to press the login button.
See the screenshots on the bellow the code.

My activity manifest declaration:

```
<activity
    android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/default_activity_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.WhiteInvertedNotificationBar" />
```

My activity style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar.BaseWhiteInvertedNotificationBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_grey</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/pure_white</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item> <!-- the problem -->
</style>
```

And my layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="br.com.gzvr.zavipro.login.LoginViewModel" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="23dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_app_logo"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/txtViewLayoutLoginMail"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_app_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewLayoutLoginMail"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_fields_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_login_mail"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_grey"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginMail"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewLogo" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputLayoutLoginMail"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_fields_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:hint="@string/edit_login_mail_hint"
                android:errorText="@{viewmodel.emailError}"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutAppearence"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtViewLayoutLoginPass"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewLayoutLoginMail"
                tools:hintEnabled="false"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/completeLoginMail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/cd_empty"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:items="@{viewmodel.cachedAccounts}"
                    android:text="@={viewmodel.email}"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    tools:text="user@mail.nil" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewLayoutLoginPass"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_fields_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="3sp"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="4dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_login_pass"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/accent_grey"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginPass"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginMail"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/inputLayoutLoginPass"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_fields_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:errorText="@{viewmodel.passwordError}"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutAppearence"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewLayoutLoginPass"
                tools:hintEnabled="false"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editLoginPass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingEnd="45dp"
                    android:hint="@string/edit_login_pass_hint"
                    android:paddingRight="45dp"
                    android:text="@={viewmodel.password}"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                    tools:text="strong" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPasswordVisibility"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_image_view_password_visibility"
                android:padding="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginPass"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginPass"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_visibility_24dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewProgress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle_progress_for_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonLoginMain"
                style="@style/GZVRNormalBlueButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_fields_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:enabled="@{viewmodel.validFields  &amp;&amp;  !viewmodel.isPostingLogin}"
                android:text="@string/button_login_main_text"
                app:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtViewResetMyPass"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLayoutLoginPass" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewResetMyPass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="@string/text_login_forgot_password"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:fontFamily="@font/opensans_semibold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonLoginMain" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

With true, as you can see the layout adjusts correctly but:
[image: "android:fitsSystemWindows" : true, snackbar goes behind the navbar]
[image: "android:fitsSystemWindows" : true, snackbar goes behind the keyboard]

With false, as you can see the snackbars appears over the keyboard and the navbar but the layout doesnt adjusts as before:

[image: "android:fitsSystemWindows" : false, snackbar goes ok, but the height didnt adjust]
[image: "android:fitsSystemWindows" : false, snackbar goes ok, but the height didnt adjust]

Answer (score 0):

show your snackbar code.

or use it in fragment:

```
Snackbar.make(getView(), "hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

in activity:

```
Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), "hello", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `fun View.showSnackbar(snackbarText: String, timeLength: Int) {
    Snackbar.make(this, snackbarText, timeLength).show()
}`

Comment: I successfully fixed this behavior using CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

1. In `AndroidManifest.xml` add this line in your activity: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
2. Use `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` in your xml to show the Snackbar message.